# Spring boot return multiple response code with message body in a POST request

Tags: rest, spring-boot

In my spring boot app, I want to return different types of response codes with response body.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/users")
public ResponseEntity<User> userSignsUp(@RequestBody User user) {

  if(userService.getUserByNic(user.getNic()).equals(userService.getUserByNic(user.getNic()))) {
    UserErrorBean userError = new UserErrorBean("User already exist","406 error");  
    return ResponseEntity<>(userError ,HttpStatus.CONFLICT); }

   userService.userSave(user);
   return ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

This is my rest  Controller and I want to return different responses based on different conditions. But it only returns condition if user NIC condition is met. If add user to database, it throws `NullPointerException()`.

I want to return responses according to the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple RestController like this.

```
@PostMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<User> userSignsUp(@RequestBody User user) {
        if(user == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        if(userService.getUserByNic(user.getNic()).equals(userService.getUserByNic(user.getNic()))) {
            UserErrorBean userError = new UserErrorBean("User already exist","406 error");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userError, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

        if(userService.userSave(user)) { // make it return boolean on success or failed
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Comment: user object do not get all values. That is why it is get nullPointExceprion.Any idea for that? If I return except ResponseEntity it will get all values

Comment: @Chamith_S Check your User class object to validate if it has all the fields same as your request json which you are sending to controller.

Comment: @Chamith_S copy paste your json and User class here, so that I can check if you are sending correct request.

Answer (score 0):

check your getter and setter method names if you are generating these in eclipse or STS.

In my case, the getter is

```
public void isActive(){
}
```

so i changed it to

```
public void getIsActive(){
}
```

It works for me.